# How to set up Umbraco to default in a subpage?

Tags: redirect, indexing, structure, default, umbraco

I have this question about umbraco structuring and I can't find the answer anywhere.

Typically in Umbraco it will default the root site to the first node of the tree.
so if we have

- Home

  - page 1
  - page 2

the default page will be home (so www.mysite.com will point to home).

How do I change this however so that www.mysite.com will point to page1 or page2?
What if I have this structure?

- wrapper

  - index
  - page 1
  - page 2

and I want www.mysite.com to go straight to www.mysite.com/index.aspx

I couldn't find a rule that does that. Tried inserting a rewrite/redirect rule and it didn't change anything.

Please help

Nick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirecting in Umbraco is usually a very simple affair, except when you're trying to redirect from the root node of your site.

**Method 1:**

It explains it best here : http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracoredirect

So it's possible by adding a `umbracoInternalRedirectId` property to your root node, with the data type of Content Picker. Note that it does not redirect the user but instead load the contents of that page inside the current url. So the URL will remain as `http://www.mysite.com` whilst serving the contents of the page that you want to redirect to.

**Method 2:**

If you really want it to change from `http://www.mysite.com/` to `http://www.mysite.com/index.aspx`. I usually add something like the following code to the template of the root node.

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/umbraco/masterpages/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<script type="c#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.com/index.aspx");    
    }
</script>
```

So that ASP.Net is responsible for the redirect. But it obviously won't handle node rename/moving too well.

Comment: No worries. Just make sure you can still save XSLTs without error (if you're even using them). That's the main reason why using Umbraco's redirect system can be so tricky on the root node, as explained in that link above.

Comment: I am only using razor instead of XSLT and the site seems to render perfectly

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect to any page using Url Rewriting
Config/UrlRewriting.config

adding this Role

```
<add name="role1"
  virtualUrl="^~/$"
  destinationUrl="~/home"
  redirect="Application"
  redirectMode="Permanent"
  ignoreCase="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick: add a rewrite rule to the Web.Config -

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to front" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/yourViewName" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Just include that inbetween the system.webServer tags within the configuration tags, and replace yourViewName by the appropriate view's name (like Contact or Work) and you're done!

All tested & works like a dream.

Cheers #

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).